# Disable routing on page refresh in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-routing, route-provider

I have a route provider like this

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');


$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
})
.when('/home', {
    resolve:{
        "check":function($location, $rootScope){
            if(!$rootScope.loggedIn){
                $location.path('/');
            }
        }
    },
    templateUrl:'home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
   });
});
```

login.html is the first page of my app.

*But after login, on reloading any page that will ends up in the login.html page*

**I want other pages keep alive on refresh and login.html as my opening page**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading page will recreate $rootScope every time. So you need to store login details in any storage like localstorage.

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/storing-data-on-the-client-with-localstorage

This link might help you. you need to store data once you successfully logged in. and get stored data and validate the use while resolving url.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, If there is any working example links? Please

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0DsmDzVBoQ&list=PL67QbqrRRyyRzUcK5qJc5AOvit5_RPE1O&index=17 this might be helpful

Comment: @RavisankarR Please mark it as answer if it works for you

Comment: it's angular 2, i'm using angular 1

Comment: Yes but use of localstorage or session storage would be same.

Answer (score 0):

```
scotchApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $compileProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
        // route for the home page

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .state('about', {
                url: '/about',
                templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
                controller  : 'aboutController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .state('contact', {
                url: '/contact',
                templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
                controller  : 'contactController'
            });

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    });
```

Try something like this.

Comment: In that link also if you reload the about page, it will redirect to home page.

Comment: Download and check in local. It's nt redirecting to home

Comment: Yeah, but it's just hash tag routing